# unable to add UI elements to bottom of android view

Tags: android

i am trying to add a scroll view in my view.All the elements show up on view properly according to my placing.i have placed "LogoutLabel" and "LogoutButton" to `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` to attach them to bottom of view.But my problem is that when i add scrollview to my view "LogoutLabel" and "LogoutButton" changes its positon and comes in middle of view i.e does not remain at bottom.i want them to be at the bottom of the view with scrolling enabled on the view.

Please anyone have solution for this.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView android:id="@+id/SettingsLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/ProfileLabel"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/EditButton"/>


<TextView android:id="@+id/MyIdLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/idLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/EmailIdLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/emailLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/PasswordIdLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/AccountLabel" />

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/LogoutLabel"
android:layout_width="200sp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Do not want to Logout?"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:textColor = "#000000"
android:paddingLeft = "10px"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/LogoutButton" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Logout" 
android:layout_alignBaseline = "@id/LogoutLabel"
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:layout_width="100sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Kartik : The link does not work.

Comment: ok. i am removing it. it was working when i got the same problem last month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the logoutLabel and logoutButton below the AccountLabel use android_layoutBelow="@id/AccountLabel"

```
    <TextView 
android:id="@+id/LogoutLabel"
android:layout_width="200sp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Do not want to Logout?"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:textColor = "#000000"
android:paddingLeft = "10px"
android:layout_below="@id/AccountLabel"/> 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/LogoutButton" 
android:layout_below="@id/AccountLabel"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Logout" 
android:layout_alignBaseline = "@id/LogoutLabel"
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:layout_width="100sp"/>
```

Hope this helps.

-Salil

Comment: Thanks salil for your answer but i know this i have use this to aling all my UI elements vertically but in my case i want these two textview and button to be aligned to bottom

Comment: Do you mean that these two controls should not be a part of the scrollView , if yes then try by creating another LinearLayout in the RelativeLayout and add the two controls there.

Comment: Nope all elements are part of scrollview but  i'll try  your suggestion of putting them in another Layout

Comment: Tried it by putting them in another layout.

Comment: its only working when i give it hard coded value like android:paddingTop = "280px" then they both sticks to bottom but i wanted it to be relatively stick to bottom than by using alignParentBottom = "true"

Comment: can you post your entire xml ?

Comment: hey got it working used android:layout_alignBottom = "id/anchor"

Comment: I was about to post an example , I used android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to align it to the bottom.

Comment: oh ok thanks for your help but if you have prepared any example please post it .It will help other users who might get in this problem.